# Blazor (Razor Components) Refresh Child Component from Parent Component

Tags: razor-pages, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

I have a simple child Blazor component (MyModal) like so:

```
<div class="modal">
    <h3>@Title</h3>
    @BodyTemplate
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter] string Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter] RenderFragment BodyTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

In my Parent component I'm calling it like so:

```
<MyModal Title="Super Cool Modal">
        <BodyTemplate>
            @MyObject.Name
        </BodyTemplate>
</MyModal>

public MyObject MyObject { get; set; } = new MyObject();
```

Later on after the page has initially rendered I update `MyObject` but the Child component itself referencing `@MyObject.Name` never updates.

Seems I have to force refresh on the child object after I've updated the Object (`StateHasChanged`) but not sure how to do this with this example.

Answer (score 22):

You can try this

**Child**

Create a public **refresh method** that you can call from parent

```
<div class="modal">
    <h3>@Title</h3>
    @BodyTemplate
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter] string Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter] RenderFragment BodyTemplate { get; set; }

    public void RefreshMe()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

**Parent**

Call child **refresh method**

```
<MyModal Title="Super Cool Modal"
         @ref="ChildComponent">
        <BodyTemplate>
            @MyObject.Name
        </BodyTemplate>
</MyModal>
@code
{
   public MyObject MyObject { get; set; } = new MyObject();
   protected UploadDownloadComponent ChildComponent;

   //Call this method to update the child
   private void Change(TreeEventArgs args)
   {
       ChildComponent.RefreshMe();
   }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting if you derive your own MyComponentBase from ComponentBase, you could add the RefreshMe() method to MyComponentBase.  Then you can inherit any of your custom components from MyComponentBase and you'll get the ability to invoke RefreshMe().  Its DRY -- arguably better than adding RefreshMe() to every single component that needs it.

Comment: What is UploadDownloadComponent?

Comment: @Yster it is the child component

Comment: This answer makes no sense. Where does this UploadDownload component come into play? That's not the child component in this question.  What is TreeEventArgs? What calls the Change function?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use CascadingParameter.

In your parent component, just call child component like this:

```
<CascadingValue Value="selectedChats[0].Id" Name="chatID">
     <AdminChatComponent> </AdminChatComponent>
</CascadingValue>
```

Child Component:

```
[CascadingParameter(Name ="chatID")]
public string chatID { get; set; }
```

After that, all you need to do is just make a OnParametersSetAsync method in child component andjust bind your value in parent component. In my case I binded my value to datagrid row select.

After that whenever binded value changes on parent component, also your child component will trigger OnParametersSetAsync method.

Answer (score 1):

Since `<MyModal>` has a `RenderFragment` parameter it's enough to call `StateHasChanged()` on the parent component, it will recalculate and render all child components with parameters from the parent.

Answer (score -1):

You can do "`OnParametersSetAsync()`" on child component:

Parent component:

```
<childCompoment param="@paramParent" />
```

Child component:

```
[Parameter]
public string param{get;set;}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){await Refresh();}

async Task Refresh(){}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer makes no sense and the code does not even match the solution they suggest i.e.OnParametersSetAsync()

Comment: The first answer doesn't work nor make any sense, either.

Answer (score -1):

I got a different example with a complex parameter object that has to be serialized to a form model.

OnParametersSetAsync() will update child component if parameter changes.

We need to bind child parameter using @bind-Job="_job"

**Parent:**

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="kt_job_tab_1">
    <JobEdit @bind-Job="_job"></JobEdit>
</div>

@code
{
    private Job _job;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _job = await GetJob();

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

}
```

**Child:**

```
<EditForm Model="@_model" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label text-sm-left text-lg-right">Title</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-xl-6">
            <InputText @bind-Value="_model.JobTitle" class="form-control form-control-solid form-control-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label text-sm-left text-lg-right">Department</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-xl-6">
            <InputText @bind-Value="_model.Department" class="form-control form-control-solid form-control-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public Job Job { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Job> JobChanged { get; set; }

    private Model _model;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        InitializeModel();

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    //THIS WILL UPDATE MODEL IF PARENT CHANGES
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        InitializeModel();

        await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }

    private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        //WE CODE HERE
        //THEN

        //THIS UPDATES PARENT IF CHILD JOB CHANGES
        await JobChanged.InvokeAsync(Job); 

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void InitializeModel()
    {
        _model = new Model
        {
            JobIdentifier = Job.Identifier,
            JobTitle = Job.JobTitle,
            Department = Job.Department
        };
    }

    private class Model
    {
        [Required]
        public string JobIdentifier { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }

}
```